# Airdrop is not working with my Mac

Tags: macos, mac, network, airdrop, network-user

I have a Macbook air 11 inch early 2014 with Mac os X 10.11.5 installed. I can't send or receive from my mac to any other iOS device. If I want to send something to my iPhone, the iPhone never scans and shows up on my mac, and If I want to send something from my iPhone, like a photo, the mac doesn't show up on my iPhone. I have followed a lot of fixes on apple discussions and other websites but non seem to work. I'd be very grateful if anyone would help me.

Comment: What fixes have you tried?

Comment: Deleting the com.apple.blutooth.plist on the preferences folder in the library directory. Also there is this thread which I had created and did everything there in: [enter link description here](https://discussions.apple.com/message/30304359?ac_cid=op123456#30304359)

Comment: Among those things, I have tried going in safe mode, reset pram and smc, signing out and in of icloud and non work. It just worked once, as I say that in the link above, I created a test account so to check it in there and it worked just one time only.

Comment: I have this problem on my Mac. I can't see my iPhone and I've tried every fix.  I ended up using a free app named [DeskConnect](http://deskconnect.com).  It does everything AirDrop does and it's always worked for me.

Comment: That's sad That i'll have to rely on some other software. There's got to be at least some way to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

For the record, Airdrop only works if you have one of these Macs, and a supported iOS device:

"*To send items to an iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch, or to receive items from those devices, you need a 2012 or later Mac model with OS X Yosemite or later, excluding the Mac Pro (Mid 2012)."*

iOS

1. iPhone 5 or later
2. iPad Pro
3. iPad (4th generation) or later
4. iPad mini or later
5. iPod touch (5th generation) or later

On the iPhone, you need to set Airdrop in Control Center, I recommend 'Everyone' just to be sure. Both wifi and bluetooth need to be on.

Comment: I have read all those sources. I have iPhone 6s and MacBook Air early 2014 version. I've added an answer and it solved the problem but then hand off didn't work which back then it used to. And when I tried to fix handoff, it started working and airdrop has stopped working again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use AirDrop regularly but I gave it a try.  Here are certain situations where my iPhone did not show up on my Mac.  1.) The phone's screen turned off, 2.) Bluetooth on either Mac or Phone was turned off.

The AirDrop functionality was not impaired or disabled when iCloud was turned off as it does not depend on your login information.  If you set the privacy and discoverability functionality on your Mac to "No One" then your iPhone cannot find your Mac; this does not affect sending to your iPhone.  As a test, I suggest you set it to "Everyone" and see if your iPhone can find it.  If so, then go to your Mac and check to see if your Mac can see your iPhone.  If so, then you're all set.  Make sure that your phone does not go into standby mode--screen turns off not just dimmed.

If all else fails, backup your information to either iCloud or your computer and reset it to factory settings.  If this does not work, I would suggest making an appointment with the Apple Geniuses.

Comment: The problem is on the Mac end. I can send and receive using airdrop with my iPhone with other macs and iOS devices but not with my Macbook Air. Also I have tried the switching "no one" to "everyone" before. In fact I try doing it often but still nothing works.

Comment: Have you performed a system integrity check from the Disk Utility application?  This will verify the integrity of system files on your Mac.  Since AirDrop is a system functionality it should check those files as well.  If there is anything wrong it should give you the option to fix it.

Comment: I did that but still the problem has not been fixed

Comment: What was the result of the integrity check?

Comment: Everything was fine.

Comment: I recommend that you back up your files and reinstall OS X.  This should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When I also signed in and out of my iCloud account from Mac, that didn't work. So I signed out and logged in *with another iCloud account*. I didn't test it right away but at night I just tried again to see if it works or not, and it did. I logged out of the account and signed in with my old iCloud account (with which airdrop wasn't working) and it worked then too.